# Simple Signin using TwitterOAuth not working

Tags: php, twitter-oauth

I need to get a user to authorise an app, so i need their access tokens.  I am using PHP and the Library TwitterOAuth.  Followed the instructions, but i am not getting redirected anywhere, even thou the $URL does work if i copy and paste it in a browser.  Here is my full code:

**UPDATE CODE**

```
require "twitteroauth/autoload.php";

use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

if (!isset($_SESSION['oauth_token'])) {
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
    $request_token = $connection->oauth('oauth/request_token', array('oauth_callback' => OAUTH_CALLBACK));
    $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $token = $request_token['oauth_token'];
    $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];
    switch ($connection->getLastHttpCode()) {
        case 200:
            $url = $connection->url('oauth/authorize', array('oauth_token' => $token));
            break;
        default:
            $error = 'Could not connect to Twitter. Refresh the page or try again later.';
    }    

} else {
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
    try {
        $access_token = $connection->oauth2("oauth/access_token", array("oauth_verifier" => $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e;
    }

    $content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');

    var_dump($content);

    echo json_encode($access_token);
}
```

So, I load the script, here is my output:

> object(stdClass)#7 (1) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#8 (2) { ["code"]=> int(89) ["message"]=> string(25) "Invalid or expired token." } } } null

I have no idea why it's not working, and help would very much appreciated!

Addy

Answer (score 1):

Comment that `var_dump($access_token);` and you wont get that second block of error.

When you print or echo something before you getting redirected (i.e you set the headers) you get this error.

Comment: Thank you, bug i cannot get it to work, or show my any errors, but it's not sending me anything, to make realise what is going on ?

Comment: `var_dump($content)` add this before the `if( !empty( $content->id )){` this and check what it gives you.

Comment: I have updated the code to what i have now, as did not need most of it, I just need the their auth tokens, as i cannot use Javascript any more.  I cannot see anything wrong with the tokens, and unsure why they would be invalid as they are new ?

Comment: This comes back as Null `$_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']`  Could this be the issue ?

Comment: Yes. The else block in the code supposed to get executed for only one time after you logged in to the twitter. So as of now 1st clear your session and try login again. You will get the desired contents.

Comment: would `session_destory;` achieve this, because I have put this at the bottom and It still will not redirect me to authorise ?